# Updating useState with server response JSON object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have a hook state that I set as an empty object with property values to start. If a property is not present, which it is not at initialization, then it calls an API, which will add the object property. This process works fine until I try to pass the response object from the API to my state hook and receive an error. If I wrap the object in another object (via curly brackets) it works, but nests the object under a property `data`.

Is there any reason why the hook only accepts wrapping the object in an object? I would prefer to just use the data object received from the server.

**Here is the error message at `setUser(data)`:**

```
Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.
```

**Here is the React Code:**

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import axios from 'axios'

export const SessionContext = createContext(null);

const AppSession = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ authenticated: false, user_id: '', user_email: ''})

    if (user){
        if(user.session_present === undefined){
            console.log("Session is not present")
            useEffect(()=> {
            axios.get('/api/auth/session/')
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('/api/auth/session/ success')
                    const data = res.data;
                    console.log(typeof(data)) // Object
                    console.log(data) // { 'authenticated': true, 'user_id':'example', 'user_email:'example', 'session_present': true }
                    setUser(data) // Doesn't work. {data} works, but nests the object to {data: { 'authenticated': true, 'user_id':'example', 'user_email:'example', 'session_present': true }}
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                });
        }, [])
        } else {
            console.log("Session is present")
        }
    } else {
        console.log("useState: Not authenticated")
        console.log(user)
    }

    return (
        <SessionContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
            {children}
        </SessionContext.Provider>
    )

}

export const getUserState = () => {
    const { user } = useContext(SessionContext)
    return user;
}

export const updateUserState = () => {
    const { setUser } = useContext(SessionContext)
    
    return (user) => {
        setUser(user);
    }
}

export default AppSession;
```

**Server code:**

```
router.route('/session/')
    .get((req, res) => {
        if(req.user){
            res.json({
                authorized: true,
                user_id: req.user.id,
                user_email: req.user.email,
                session_present: true
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                authorized: false,
                user_id: '',
                user_email: ''
            })
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Hooks cannot be called conditionally. Every time a given component renders it must call exactly the same number of hooks in exactly the same order. So you need to take those `if`s that are currently outside the `useEffect` and move them inside.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    if (user.session_present === undefined) {
      axios
        .get("/api/auth/session/")
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("/api/auth/session/ success");
          const data = res.data;
          setUser(data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      console.log("Session is present");
    }
  } else {
    console.log("useState: Not authenticated");
    console.log(user);
  }
}, []);
```

For more information, see [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

---

And the reason you didn't get the error when you set state with an object is that by putting your data in a bad format, you made it so `user.session_present` was always `undefined`. Since it was always `undefined`, the `useEffect` always got called, so the rules of hooks were being obeyed.